# Imperative for ‘розповісти’, the second person

Tags: дієслова, conjugation

> **This question also has been asked here (in Ukrainian):**
> *["Дайте відповідь" одним словом](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/7136)*

What are the imperative forms of verb *розповісти*, *відповісти* etc. for the second person?

Some say they must end with `дж`: *розповідж*, *розповіджте*. It sounds unusual but I've seen this kind of conjugation in a dialect-based translation:

```
Повіджте, вуйку, ци не задарь…
```

Others say that the only reputable option for *відповісти* are respective forms of *дати відповідь*. But it doesn't explain what to do with *розповісти*, *оповісти*, *заповісти*…

Comment: Isn't `Повіджте, вуйку, ци не задарь...` [rusyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rusyn_language)?

Comment: Історично особові форми _[відпо]вісти_ мали такі ж самі закінчення, як і дієслово _їсти_, бо обидва належать до т.з. класу нетематичних дієслів, закінчення в них приєднуються безпосередньо до кореня. В слов’янських мовах їх усього 5 (бути, дати, їсти, [відпо]вісти, та імати [імам, імаш] – цей останній у нас тут випав), впізнаються вони по закінченню _-м_ в 1 ос. одн. тепер. ч.: _відповім - їм, відповіси - їси, відповімо - їмо, відповідять - їдять_, тому (а історично так і було) наказ. спос. 2 ос. одн. має бути як _іж!_, тобто _відповіж!_ Це абсолютно орґанічна форма й є в инш. слов’ян. мовах.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The term you are looking for is **Defective verb**, and yes, *розповісти* is one of these verbs.

[Wikipedia: Defective verb #Ukrainian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb#Ukrainian) says:

> Verbs ending on `-вісти`: *розповісти* ("to tell", perfective) and *відповісти* ("to answer", perfective) lack imperative mood forms; **imperfective verbs are used instead** (*розповідай* *відповідай*).

---

Just if you wonder why, [this article](http://pravopys.kiev.ua/pravopys.aspx?SectionID=2569) has a nice explanation:

> **Окрему архаїчну дієвідміну** мають дієслова: *дати, їсти, вісти* (у сучасній мові тільки з префіксами — *відповісти, розповісти*) і *бути*.

So, these verbs belong to an archaic declension group and don't follow the common rules of grammar.

Comment: Thanks. I take it we can deal with it either by using Imperfective case instead or by finding a substitute, a synonym, as a child would do: „Розкажи мені казку!”

Comment: @SassaNF, BTW this would be a great (separate) question. We all employ intuition here, but someone may want to learn about the formal rules for stressing the verbs in imperative mood ending with `-ай` and `-уй`.

Comment: @SassaNF, I think, Wikipedia article means, lack ≠ absence; lack = certain forms are missing, but the others exist. IOW, the **perfective** is missing, but the **imperfective** exists and is used instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53648/discussion-between-bytebuster-and-sassa-nf).

Comment: This answer provides useful information, but I am not if it's complete, because it lacks information about how a speaker can actually say “Tell me!” in Ukrainian. I.e. it explains why the straight scheme for building imperative mood doesn't work for this word — but doesn't provide any information about alternative ways.

Comment: @Sasha, the alternative is, *“imperfective verbs are used instead (розповідай, відповідай)”*. Yes, it's a bit uncomfortable as many would prefer a direct equivalent, but it is the only answer I found so far.

Comment: Still, Wikipedia isn't right in "imperfective verbs are used instead". The more correct phrase should be: "imperfective verbs *or one of the huge number of synonyms* are used instead". And, IMHO, at least few of them should be present somewhere within this question (*not necessary in this answer*) to make reading this page fully useful to a user.