# Як буде "ответь" українською? "Ответь мне". Не роби, а зроби

Tags: дієслова, наказовий-спосіб, дієвідмінювання

Ймовірний контекст:

> Когда я позвоню, ты лучше ответь мне.
>
> Коли я зателефоную, ти краще *…яке тут слово?…* мені.

Йдеться про наказовий спосіб дієслова "відповісти" доконаного виду теперішнього часу. В сучасних словниках ми не знайдемо такої форми. Пишуть, що не утворюється. Але в правописному словнику Г. Голосевича за 1929 читаємо:  *відпові́ж*, `-ві́жмо`, `-ві́жте` і рідше `-ві́дж`, `-ві́джте`. Крім того, цю форму (*"відповідж"* або *"відповіж"*) використовували деякі наші класики, зокрема О. Кобилянська, І. Франко, Стефаник і навіть Василь Стус.

То може краще замість "дай відповідь" (*рос. ответь*) казати *"відповідж"/"відповіж"*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Imperative for ‘розповісти’, the second person](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/392/imperative-for-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%96%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-the-second-person)

Comment: Погоджуюсь, що питання цікаве, але 'відповідж' звучить жахливо.

Comment: @bytebuster, this isn't a duplicate at least because this question is in Ukrainian and that question was in English, while our [most popular opinion about cross-language duplicates is "keep both"](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3/4).

Comment: @bytebuster, з іншого боку — таке формулювання справді провокує «opinion-based» відповіді (тобто відповіді, що базуються на особистій думці, а не на фактах). Я, здається, знаю, як переформулювати, щоб не провокувало. Але не вважаю себе вправі змінювати суть питання.

Comment: Голосую за закриття. Питання дійсно цікаве, але виходить за рамки stackexchange, оскільки вимагає розширеної дискусії. Автор може продовжити на сторонніх форумах. Наприклад: 1) темі Словника [Відповіж, відповіжте, Чи можливо вживати] (http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=598) 2) Наказовий спосіб дієслова "відповісти" http://tereveni.org/topic/26240/

Comment: Історично особові форми _[відпо]вісти_ мали такі ж самі закінчення, як і дієслово _їсти_, бо обидва належать до т.з. класу нетематичних дієслів, закінчення в них приєднуються безпосередньо до кореня. В слов’янських мовах їх усього 5 (бути, дати, їсти, [відпо]вісти, та імати [імам, імаш] – цей останній у нас тут випав), впізнаються вони по закінченню _-м_ в 1 ос. одн. тепер. ч.: _відповім - їм, відповіси - їси, відповімо - їмо, відповідять - їдять_, тому (а історично так і було) наказ. спос. 2 ос. одн. має бути як _іж!_, тобто _відповіж!_ Це абсолютно орґанічна форма й є в инш. слов’ян. мовах.

Comment: "Коли я зателефоную, тобі краще мені відповісти" - це якщо  "дослівно". А українською: "коли зателефоную, краще бери слухавку!"

Answer (score 6):

Існує інше дієслово зі значенням *"відповідати"*: [*відказувати*](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/6842-vidkazuvaty.html#show_point). Пропоную використовувати наказове *відкажіть*, або *відпишіть*, залежно від контексту.

Answer (score 3):

Суб'єктивно мені не подобається форма *відповідж* чи *відповіж* і може й добре, що такої форми немає в сучасних правилах.

В цьому конкретному випадку можна відповісти таким чином:

> Коли я зателефоную, **тобі краще відповісти мені**.

Answer (score 2):

Дїєслово *відповісти* належе до окремої дїєвідміни, як виняткову. Правопис [2019 року](https://files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf) виокремює такі: *да́ти*, *ї́сти*, ***відпові́сти́***, *розпові́сти́* i *бути*. І подає такі відмінки.

| Особа | Однина | Множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *1* | відпові́м | відповімо́ |
| *2* | відповіси́ | відповісте́ |
| *3* | відпові́сть | даду́ть ві́дповідь |

Як бачимо, третя особа множини майбутнього часу відсутня, як і наш наказовий, натомість радять вживати ***дати* + відповідь**, а отже *дайте відповідь* чи десь так.

---

Якшчо забути про державну українську і поглянути шчодо *відповіж* і *відповідж*. Таке справді є, особливо якшчо дїєслова, котрі на *-сти*,
запишуть ся в повноцїнну третю дїєвідміну. Сюди входять ті ж згадані дїєслова, хіба шчо можна виокремити *єсти* і викинути *бути*. Тоді мати ймемо десь таку будову, якшчо брати сучасну правописну.

Наказовий

| Особа | Однина | Множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *1* |  | -жмо |
| *2* | -ж | -жте |

Майбутнїй чи теперїшний час, залеже від доконаностьи

| Особа | Однина | Множина |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *1* | -м | -мо |
| *2* | -си | -сте |
| *3* | -сть | -дять |

Минулий

| Число | Чоловічий | Жїночий | Середнїй |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *Однина* | -в | -ла | -ло |
| *Множина* | -ли | -ли | -ли |

Тому на *їж* — *відповіж*, a на *[їдж](https://nashe.com.ua/song/24212)* — *відповідж*. Зараз *да(д)ж* звучати йме дуже дивно, але воно досї стрїчає ся в слові як *[да(д)жбог](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3)* проти *дайбог*.

Не зовсїм по темі, але зазначу, же ця дїєвідміна може наближувати ся до гинших, наприклад заміна *-си* на *-(и)ш*: *їш* ~ *їсиш*, *даш* ~ *дасиш* ітд; шче мати гинші відгалуження, [нп](https://shron2.chtyvo.org.ua/Naukove_tovarystvo_imeni_Shevchenka/Khronika_Ch_52.pdf#page=13) *-си* на *-сь*: *дась*, *їсь* ітд; або вже згадане тут *-дж* замість *-ж*.

Answer (score 0):

Дієслова дати, їсти і відповісти (розповісти) не належать ні до першої, ні до другої дієвідміни. Це тзв. архаїчна дієвідміна. Їсти і відповісти відмінюються за одним зразком.
Отже, їм, відповім
їси, відповіси
їдять, відповідять
їж, відповіж ітд.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Хоча цей допис, теоретично, може містити відповідь, було б набагато краще, якби він містив обґрунтування на основі посилань на авторитетні джерела та/або академічні дослідження. Дописи, що не містять обґрунтування, часто спричиняють «мінусування» та диспути.