# "Дайте відповідь" одним словом

Tags: словотворення, одним-словом

> **Це запитання також має відповідь (англійською):**
> *[Imperative for ‘розповісти’, the second person](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/392)*

Чи можна замість *дай(/те) відповідь* казати *відповід(и/ідь)*?

Чи правильний такий словотвір з точки зору мовних правил? Поки мені здається, що правильний, бо є ж сходіть, віднесіть. Додати приросток як у випадку *копайте* мабуть не вийде, бо вже є приросток *від*.

```
ідіть         | копайте         | відносьте | відповідайте 
(про/ви)йдіть | (про/ви)копайте | віднесіть | ?відповідідь
```

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/504/8

Comment: @Bocchi не знаю що таке sic, а щодо іншого, то можливо дійсно треба було це вказати: перший рядок таблиці це те, що я знаю, а другий рядок це те, що я хочу. Я намагався порівняти з іншими словами. *Відповідідь* це моя спроба словоформи як *пройдіть/викопайте/віднесіть*. Тобто мене цікавила саме доконана дія, бо недоконану я і так знаю, я її вказав у першому рядку.

Comment: 1) [sic](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic). 2) Я наче указав: а) чому ті, через декілька причин, дѣєслова підібрані неправильно, б) *від-* не грає різницї і відки походить, в) навѣв доконаного *відповѣсти*.

Answer (score 3):

> *Дайте відповідь* одним словом

[Гісторічно](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F), словянська мова мала пять класів дїєслів. В нашому випадку цїкавить [пятий](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B1), котрий відомий також як атематичний або [безсуфіксний](//webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lSs4T3DVJQQJ://kspu.edu/FileDownload.ashx/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F%208.%20%D0%94%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE.docx). Погляньмо на ций клас?

Теперїшнїй час

| Інфінітів | *dati | *věděti | *(j)ěsti | *byti |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Перша особа однини | *damь | *věmь | *(j)ěmь | *(j)esmь |
| Друга особа однини | *dasi | *věsi | *(j)ěsi | *(j)esi |
| Третя особа однини | *dastь | *věstь | *(j)ěstь | *(j)estь |
| Перша особа множини | *damъ | *věmъ | *(j)ěmъ | *(j)esmъ |
| Друга особа множини | *daste | *věste | *(j)ěste | *(j)este |
| Третя особа множини | *dadętь | *vědętь | *(j)ědętь | *sǫtь |

Наказовий спосіб

| Інфінітів | *dati | *věděti | *(j)ěsti | *byti |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Друга й третя особи однини | dadji | vědjь | jědjь | bǫdi |
| Перша особа множини | dadimъ | vědimъ | jědimъ | bǫděmъ |
| Друга особа множини | dadite | vědite | jědite | bǫděte |

Тобто де лише дїєслова як *дати*, *відати*, *їсти*, *бути* і їхнї похідні. Тому порівнювати треба саме з такими, крім *бути*, котре відрізняїть ся від гинших на таблицї і є [сполукою](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/byti) двох дїєслів як *бути* і *єсти*. Тим паче *їсти*, *дати*, *відати* мають наказовий спосіб, причому перше ± зберегло структуру, а гинші уподібнили ся до першої дїєвідміни, хоча декотрі елементи зберегли ся в декотрих словах як [*Да(д)жбог*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3).

Тому канонічно буде відмінювати за [*їсти*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D1%97%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Для прикладу додам *відповідати*, але змінене під потреби.

| Інфінітів | їсти | відповісти | відповідати |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Друга особа однини | їж | **відповіж** | відповідаж |
| Перша особа множини | їжмо | **відповіжмо** | відповідажмо |
| Друга особа множини | їжте | **відповіжте** | відповідажте |

Або ж за [*дати*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8#335772), котре частково уподібнилося до першої дїєвідміни, де зазвичай відбуваїть ся заміна *-ти* на *-й-* в наказових способах, а також до третьої особи множини додають наросток *-уть*. Тобто як в згаданому слові *копати*.

| Інфінітів | дати | відповісти | відповідати |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Друга особа однини | дай | відповій | **відповідай** |
| Перша особа множини | даймо | відповіймо | **відповідаймо** |
| Друга особа множини | дайте | відповійте | **відповідайте** |

Де тут *відповідати* вже не змінене і є в [словниках](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), но і походить від того ж згаданого вище [*відати*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8). Тому *дати відповідь*, втч. за правописом, це до *відповісти*, а не *відповідати*, котрого ви розбирали тут і котре було би як *давати відповідь*. Тому дещо дуже дивно бачити:

- спроби гадати як дїєслово *відповідати* відмінюїть ся, при цьому не перевіривши словники,
- брати за приклад неправильні дїєслова, тобто котрі міняють корінь: *і**т**и* → *і**д**їть*, *відн**о**сити* → *відн**е**сїть*, а тому можуть також мати декотрі відхилення, бо часто це сполука двох дїєслів.

Comment: Дякую, та мене цікавить саме завершена дія - *дайте відповідь* це подібно *з'їж* на відміну від *давайте відповідь*, що подібно до *їж*.

Comment: Дивно, в запитанні доволі чітко показане бажання дізнатись про саме доконану дію, наприклад, другий рядок в табличні, що я навів подає доконані дії. Також не знайшов, де у відповіді сказань, що такого немає.

Comment: Вкажіть, будь ласка, де ви навели відповідник до *дайте відповідь* або вказали, що його немає?

Comment: @Yola цітую: _Тому **дати відповідь**, втч. за правописом, це до **відповісти**, а не відповідати, котрого ви розбирали тут і котре було би як давати відповідь._

Comment: То як же це до *відповісти*? Запитання про те як це сказати одним словом, а те від *відповісти* чи від *відповідати* це слово буде для мене неважливо.